# Pandas dataframe replace values on multiple column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, replace

I have a dataframe df_merchandise with two columns of interest, ProductType and ProductDescription. One of the values for ProductType is 'Accessory' which can have multiple different values for ProductDescription, such as 'Lamp', 'Mirror', etc. How would I do a conditional replacement like the following:

```
If (df_merchandise.ProductType == 'Accessory') and (df_merchandise.ProductDescription == 'Mirror'):
     replace 'Accessory' with 'Mirror'
```

The key here being that I only replace the value of ProductType for ProductDescription if the row value for PType is 'accessory' **AND** the row value for PDesc. is 'Mirror'.
[image: pandas dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original DF is

```
  ProductDescription ProductType
0                Art   Accessory
1             Mirror   Accessory
2        Western Art   Accessory
3             Tassel   Accessory
4           Hardware   Accessory
5             Mirror   Accessory
```

You can do the following:

```
mirror_filter = (df['ProductType'] == 'Accessory') & (df['ProductDescription'] == 'Mirror')
df.loc[mirror_filter, 'ProductType'] = df['ProductDescription']
```

And your resulting DF should be:

```
  ProductDescription ProductType
0                Art   Accessory
1             Mirror      Mirror
2        Western Art   Accessory
3             Tassel   Accessory
4           Hardware   Accessory
5             Mirror      Mirror
```

Comment: Excellent. Much simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way i can use regex to filter by phrase? Say I wanted to perform the same replacement as above, but searching for all instances of 'table' in ProductDescription. returned values could be 'side table', 'end table', etc. I am struggling to find if theres a way to do this in a conditional statement when filtering.

Comment: I am trying series.str.contains('table', na=False, regex=False) but it only returns values in PD that contain table in the full string, excluding standalone 'Table' values. (returns 'Sidetable', 'Endtable', but not just 'Table')

Comment: You can try `Series.str.contains('table', case=False)`. This way the matching pattern becomes case insensitive.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to merge this back to the main df. I tried `table_filter = (df_merchandise['ProductType'] == 'Accessory') & (df_merchandise['ProductDescription'].str.contains('table', case=False))
table_filter.ProductType = table_filter.replace({'ProductType': 'Accessory'}, 'Table')
df_merchandise.loc[table_filter, 'ProductType'] = df_merchandise['ProductDescription']` but my resulting value counts for 'table' only went up 3 and I know there were more than 3 instances of table being added. I'm assuming the error is in replacing but I dont understand why this doesnt work

Comment: actually I see it's probably in the last line, `df_merchandise.loc[table_filter, 'ProductType'] = df_merchandise['ProductDescription']` when I am swapping with PD instead it should be PT which I tried to set as 'table' for all instances where table occurs in PD....

Comment: Just let me know what you're trying to do. You want to replace the `ProductType` with the word `Table` for all the rows that have a match with `table` in `ProductDescription`, right?

Comment: If so, you may just do `df.loc[table_filter, 'ProductType'] = 'Table'`